# MinGW's gcc reports error where Cygwin's accepts

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw

MingGW's gcc (4.8.1) reports the following error (and more to come) when I try to compile Expstack.c:

```
  parser.h:168:20: error: field '__p__environ' declared as a function
        struct term *environ;
```

where 'environ' is declared inside 'struct term{ ... }'.  In unistd.h you find

```
  char **environ
```

but nowhere a '__p__environ'.

Some other fields are declared likewise, but are accepted.  Subsequent errors related to environ are reported as follows

```
  Expstack.c:1170:38: error: expected identifier before '(' token
  case Term_src: return e->item.src->environ;
                                  ^
```

Cygwin's gcc (4.8.3) accepts these constructs and has done so over various versions since
2006 at least, and gcc with various versions of Linux before that.

The source text uses CRLF despite my attempts to convert to DOS, and this is my only guess for an explanation.

I'll appreciate clues or ideas to fix the problem, but renaming the field is not especially attractive and ought to be totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unlikely to have to do with CR/LF.

The name ought to be irrelevant but it isn't: this one relates to the Windows integration that MinGW does and Cygwin does not, as alluded to in http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/14901207/ (that person is trying to use an extern `environ` that it expects to be defined by the system. Clearly, the fashion in which MinGW developers have made this variable available breaks the use of the name as a struct member).

You should report this as a MinGW bug. Unpleasant as it may be, in the interim, renaming the member is the simplest workaround. It is possible that a well-placed `#undef environ` might help, but no guarantees.

Comment: The MinGW developers aren't going to accept it as a bug, since it doesn't define `environ` when compiling in strict ANSI compliance mode.

Comment: @RossRidge So would the solution to the OP's problem not be to compile in this mode? Can I suggest that you say how in an answer?